# How to detect if a user likes a certain facebook page on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I know a lot of apps give you some sort of bonus when you like their Facebook page. I am wondering how do I implement a function that detects whether a user likes a Facebook page on Android.

---

My progress so far: I have read Facebook documentation and know that it has something to do with a HTML GET with a url like facebook.com/userid/likes/facebook_page_id

Comment: I’m not sure what you want to know specifically … you seem to know how to ask if a user likes a certain page already, so what’s the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to implement this on Android in details. For example, what url should I use, graph.facebook.com? And the overall structure of the function.

Comment: Of course you use that URL, because that’s in no way dependent on the platform you’re on. And for the “overall structure of the function” … well, have it make the HTTP request and interpret the response …

Comment: CBroe basically gave you the answer. Find the ID for the page you want to check if the user is a fan of. Then parse the JSON response from the Facebook API and go through the results until you either find a matching ID, either you reach the end. If you find a matching ID, the user is a fan. Your question is more of a code related question, but you didn't show us what you tried already, coding-wise, and how it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Facebook & Java

We do similar stuff for a Website running on Java, you might want to try this Facebook Graph API Java Implementation http://restfb.com/

This makes such stuff very easy...
http://restfb.com/#fetching-single-objects

And the best part: It's OpenSource! (MIT License)

Comment: It does not work. The Pages class just brings the getLikes() method. It does not tell you WHO liked the page.